# How to convert callback sample to deferred object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, promise

I have a function that accepts a callback function where I pass the data back in. Can this converted to a deferred object for better practice?

Here is what I got:

```
    var chapters;
    var getChapters = function (fnLoad) {
        //CACHE DATA IF APPLICABLE
        if (!chapters) {
            //CALL JSON DATA VIA AJAX
            $.getJSON('/chapters.txt')
                .done(function (json) {
                    //STORE DATA IN LOCAL STORAGE
                    chapters = Lawnchair(function () {
                        this.save(json, function (data) {
                            //CALL CALLBACK ON DATA
                            fnLoad(data);
                        });
                    });
                });
        } else {
            //RETURN ALREADY CREATED LOCAL STORAGE
            chapters.all(function (data) {
                //CALL CALLBACK ON DATA
                fnLoad(data);
            });
        }
    };
```

Then I simply use it like this:

```
this.getChapters(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

How can I use it like a promise though while maintaining the cache approach?

```
this.getChapters().done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: jQuery's ajax methods extend the deferred object.  You're already using it...

Comment: But notice I'm manipulating the data and using "Lawnchair" somewhere in the middle before passing back the data, so I can't jsut return the ajax object right?

Comment: Why are your comments in all caps?

Comment: I like the convention since it's easier to point out. No offense :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var chapters;
var getChapters = function (fnLoad) {
    var d = new $.Deferred();
    //CACHE DATA IF APPLICABLE
    if (!chapters) {
        //CALL JSON DATA VIA AJAX
        $.getJSON('/chapters.txt')
            .done(function (json) {
                //STORE DATA IN LOCAL STORAGE
                chapters = Lawnchair(function () {
                    this.save(json, function (data) {
                        //CALL CALLBACK ON DATA
                        d.resolve(data);
                    });
                });
            })
            .fail(function() { d.reject(); });
    } else {
        //RETURN ALREADY CREATED LOCAL STORAGE
        chapters.all(function (data) {
            //CALL CALLBACK ON DATA
            d.resolve(data);
        });
    }
    return d.promise();
};
```

[Relevant example](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)

Answer (score 2):

I see you have already accepted an answer, however if you take a large mental leap and store a promise of `chapters` instead of the `chapters` themselves, then the code will simplify significantly.

These days, this is probably the more generally adopted approach for a "fetch/cache" situation.

```js
var chapters_promise;
var getChapters = function () {
    //Cache data if applicable and return promise of data
    if (!chapters_promise)
        chapters_promise = $.getJSON('/chapters.txt').then(Lawnchair).then(this.save);
    return chapters_promise;
};
```

What is actually promised (the chapters) will be determined by the value(s) returned by the functions `Lawnchair` and `this.save`, so you still have some work to do.

`getChapters()` will always return a promise, regardless of whether the data needs to be fetched or is already cached. Therefore, `getChapters()` can only be used with promise methods `.then()`, `.done()`, `.fail()` or `.always()`, for example :

```
getChapters().then(fnLoad);
```

You have no other way to access the `chapters` but that is reasonable since at any call of `getChapters()`, you don't know whether it will follow the `$.getJSON()` branch or the simple `return` branch, both of which return an identical promise.