# How to force trigger ajax success (want to resolve the deferred object manually)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, local-storage, promise, deferred

Background: I'm making a caching mechanism for (json response only) jQuery ajax calls. Upon a successful ajax call I store some data in localstorage: the key which is an identifier specific to the request (I concatenate the `method` and the `url`), and the value is the JSON response, along with some metadata like how long until expiration. Upon a second ajax call to the same url with the same method, I check to see if the item exists in localstorage.

Problem: If there a valid entry in localstorage, I want to stop the ajax request to the server, and then trigger a successful ajax response- and inject my localstorage data as the `responseJSON`.

I see jquery uses the status code to determine a successful ajax response:

```
// Determine if successful
isSuccess = status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304;
```

And then later on resolves the deferred:

```
// Success/Error
if ( isSuccess ) {
    deferred.resolveWith( callbackContext, [ success, statusText, jqXHR ] );
} else {
    deferred.rejectWith( callbackContext, [ jqXHR, statusText, error ] );
}
```

Is there a way I can access the jQuery deferred from the $.ajaxPrefilter() method (which is the hook I'm using to do my logic)? If I can access the deferred object I think I could resolve it on my own and then cancel the ajax request with `jqXHR.abort()` ?

Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/jaredrada/7185419

Comment: See similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639408/how-to-convert-callback-sample-to-deferred-object/17640142). The difference is your desire to use localstorage. You will need to adapt the selected answer. Don't try to use the other answer (by me) - it won't work with localstorage because Promises can't (as far as I'm aware) be reliably stringified (localstorage only stores strings or stringified data).

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I like that solution, which essentially wraps the jquery ajax function and returns the deferred obj (whether from an ajax call or from cached data). I was taking a different approach, modifying the ajax mechanism itself. Thanks for the help.